# Bootstrap assets don't load when deployed django on Heroku

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

Deployed my django project on Heroku. I use bootstrap hosted on maxcdn.

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css

In mobile version everything is Ok. But in desktop version page renders without bootstrap assets. On local server everything is also works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the URL of your project?

Comment: clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Loaded bootstrap.min.css into my static folder. Now works fine.

template

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" media="screen, projection"/>
```

Comment: Few hours it worked fine, but after pushing updates page again shows without bootstrap styles.

Comment: Same problem facing!